# How can I add x number of leading spaces in a string using Bash?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, indentation

`x` contains the number of characters to add. How can I add `$x` number of characters to a text line?

```
sed -i s/^/   /
```

`sed` does the job, but the number of spaces must be typed. In my case, the number of spaces is in a calculated variable.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `printf` with a field width specification.

```
line=$(printf "%*s%s" $x '' "$line")
echo "$line"
```

`*` means to get the width from the argument `$x`. Then it prints an empty string in a field with that width, and follows it with the original value of `$line`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the suggestion, but it does not work. the printf statement is ok without the $( ). But the code do no assign the variable line with the leading spaces.  
Here is a code sample :   
line="123"  
echo $line  
x=3  
printf "%*s%s\n" $x " " "$line"  
line=$(printf "%*s%s" $x ' ' "$line")  
echo $line  
It output  
123  
   123  
123

Comment: Put the variable in quotes when you echo it: `echo "$line"`. You should almost *always* quote your variables.

Answer (score 4):

Using awk

```
x=3; awk -v x="$x" '{printf "%" x "s%s\n", "", $0}' file
```

or

```
x=3; awk '{printf "%"'$x'"s%s\n", "", $0}' file
```

Comment: Hi, I have an issue if "file" is a variable like in awk '{printf "%"'$blanks'"s%s\n", "", $0}' ${entry[1]} > /tmp/entry.tmp. The filename in ${entry[1]} is not recognized. Thanks

Comment: in fact, the issue is the ${entry[1]} contains ~ character at the beginning

Comment: What if you try `"${entry[1]}"`?